# Writing a code / query that runs after midnight using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I just wanted to ask a simple question about MongoDB and javascript (express js).

Here are my requirements:

I am trying to create a back-end service for films and series. I created most of the basic routes and functions. I want to pick a film from the database for the "Movie Of The Day" subtitle.

My Function:

```
function filterFilmsForImbd(films,imbd){
    let filmChances = [];
    films.filter(film=>{
        if(film.imbdScore >= imbd){
            filmChances.push(film);
        };
    });
    return filmChances;
};

//Movie Of The Day
function movieOfTheDay(films) {
    const date = new Date();
    if (date.getHours() >= 0) {
        let arr = filterFilmsForImbd(films,7)
        let numberOfFilmChances = arr.length;
        let randomFilmPicker = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfFilmChances);
        return arr[randomFilmPicker]//returns object (film object)
    };
};

//Recommended Films
function recommendedMovies(films){
   return  filterFilmsForImbd(films,5);
};
```

I wrote a function that can run after midnight (00:00) but when I refresh the page it keeps continue to get random data.

How can I create a function that can pick a movie randomly just once a day?

Do you want me to extend my question with my routes? Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

For nodejs, a good package for this will be [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

Running a function after midnight will be

```
import cron from 'node-cron';
 
cron.schedule('0 0 0 * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task at midnight');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set an interval and run your code using `setInterval` method.

```
setInterval(movieOfTheDay, 86400000);
```

`movieOfTheDay` function will call after 86400000 milliseconds(A Day in milliseconds).

And remove the if condition in the `movieOfTheDay`, it is always true since `date.getHours()` gives a positive value.

Learn more about the setInterval method: [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it sounds very logical, but isn't it the same error I fell for? Won't the 24-hour countdown start over with each refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` to check the time every minute, and if it’s midnight, run the code. eg:

```js
setInterval(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    if(date.getMinutes() == 0 && date.getHours() == 0) {
        // code code code... lalalala
    }
}, 1000);
```

This will keep it running even if you reload the page.